# Product image upload issue on magento 1.9.3.10

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, magento-1.9.3.10

I have upgraded the site from **1.9.2.2** to **1.9.3.10**

There is an issue with catalog product page in admin.

When uploading the image, it shows complete but thumbnail is not displayed.
Images are uploaded to `tmp/catalog/product`.

I have tried all the solution, still no luck.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Please open the developer tool of the browser while uploading the image and inspect the "Console" tab for any Javascript error. This should possibly give the reason for the problem.

Comment: There is no error in console. After uploading images, ajax response is true.

Comment: In that case, try changing permissions for media directory to 777 recursively and also check if flash is turned ON for the website(in case you are browsing in chrome)

Comment: Already tried. Still no luck.